# Limit of characteristic function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, residue-calculus

I have a characteristic function defined as the following:

$$\phi(\frac{t}{N})^N = (\alpha E_{\alpha+1}(-\frac{iLt}{N}))^N$$

where $E_n(z)$ is the $E_n$ function having the form $E_n(z) = \int^\infty_1 \frac{e^{-zm}dm}{m^n}$. And the limit is supposed to equal:

$$ \lim_{N \to \infty} (\alpha \int^\infty_1 \frac{e^{\frac{-iLtm}{N}}dm}{m^{\alpha+1}})^N= e^{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}iLt}.$$
for $\alpha > 1$ and $N$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ and $L$ is a positive constant. I don't see why this limit holds, any ideas?

Comment: You used $t$ to mean two different things.  So the last displayed equation doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith yes I did, I just fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever we say "bounded", we mean it is bounded by a constant that doesn't depend on $N$.

Integrate by parts twice:
$$ \alpha \int^\infty_1 \frac{e^{\frac{-iLtm}{N}}dm}{m^{\alpha+1}} $$
$$ = - \left[ \frac{e^{\frac{-iLtm}{N}}}{m^{\alpha}} \right]^\infty_1  - \frac{iLt}{N}\int^\infty_1 \frac{e^{\frac{-iLtm}{N}}dm}{m^{\alpha}} $$
$$ = e^{\frac{-iLtm}{N}} + \left[ \frac{iLt}{N}\frac1{\alpha-1}\frac{e^{\frac{-iLtm}{N}}}{m^{\alpha-1}} \right]^\infty_1 + \left(\frac{iLt}{N}\right)^2\frac1{\alpha-1}\int^\infty_1 \frac{e^{\frac{-iLtm}{N}}dm}{m^{\alpha-1}} $$
$$ = e^{\frac{-iLtm}{N}} - \frac{iLt}{N}\frac1{\alpha-1}e^{\frac{-iLtm}{N}} + \left(\frac{iLt}{N}\right)^2\frac1{\alpha-1}\int^\infty_1 \frac{e^{\frac{-iLtm}{N}}dm}{m^{\alpha-1}} $$
If $\alpha>2$, then $\int^\infty_1 \frac{e^{\frac{-iLtm}{N}}dm}{m^{\alpha-1}}$ is bounded, so what if $1 < \alpha \le 2$?
$$ \int^\infty_1 \frac{e^{\frac{-iLtm}{N}}dm}{m^{\alpha-1}} = N^{2-\alpha}\int^\infty_{1/N} \frac{e^{-iLtm}dm}{m^{\alpha-1}} $$
$$ = N^{2-\alpha}\int^1_{1/N} \frac{e^{-iLtm}dm}{m^{\alpha-1}}
+ N^{2-\alpha}\int^\infty_{1} \frac{e^{-iLtm}dm}{m^{\alpha-1}} .$$
If $\alpha < 2$, then $\int^1_{1/N} \frac{e^{-iLtm}dm}{m^{\alpha-1}}$ is bounded by $\int^1_{0} \frac{1}{m^{\alpha-1}}$, which is bounded by the $p$-test.  If $\alpha = 2$, a similar argument shows it is bounded by $\log N$.

As for the other part, we integrate by parts the other way:
$$ \int^\infty_{1} \frac{e^{-iLtm}dm}{m^{\alpha-1}} $$
$$ =\left[ \frac1{-iLtm}\frac{e^{-iLtm}}{m^{\alpha-1}} \right]^\infty_{1} - \frac{\alpha-1}{-iLtm}\int^\infty_{1} \frac{e^{-iLtm}dm}{m^{\alpha}} $$
and again we get something bounded.

Putting it all together, we get
$$ \alpha \int^\infty_1 \frac{e^{\frac{-iLtm}{N}}dm}{m^{\alpha+1}} = e^{\frac{-iLtm}{N}}\left(1 - \frac{iLt}{N}\frac1{\alpha-1} + o(N^{-1})\right) .$$

Comment: Ok thanks Stephen I'll work on it. nice website btw.

Comment: Ok Stephen, I can't do it. Can you give me more details?

Comment: It turned out to be rather harder than I thought.  The argument I gave worked if $\alpha>2$.  But for $1<\alpha\le2$, it needed a lot more work.  Please check my work for correctness.

Comment: Yes your computations are correct. So to finish off the answer, I have to take the limit as $N$ goes to Infinity, it seems that the characteristic function will have value 1, so the density function , by taking the inverse fourier transform will be a delta function centered at 0 times $\sqrt{2\pi}$, is this correct?

Comment: You take it to the power of $N$ before letting $N \to \infty$.  I get almost the answer you wrote in the original question, but I have a negative sign in the exponent.

Comment: did you get $e^{\frac{(a-1)iLt}{a}}$?

Comment: No, I got $e^{-\frac\alpha{\alpha-1} iLt}$.

Comment: How did you take the limit, can you give me details?

Comment: BTW i was not familiar with assymptotic expansion of integrals but after I researched some things you wrote in your answer I learned a few things thanks!